# Data Distribution in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have heard about Cassandra and its distribution. Actually want to know phenomena how data are distributed in the whole cluster? i mean How does Cassandra decide which nodes have what data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of nodes (a single node, or several) responsible for any given piece of data is determined by:

- The row key (data is partitioned on row key)
- The replication factor
- The replication strategy

It is important to understand that Cassandra does not alter the replica set for a given row key based on changing characteristics like current load, which nodes are up or down, or which node your client happens to talk to.

For more details go through [cassandra FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ)

Answer (score 5):

Pretty simple if you understand the HastTable data structure and how hashing is done in Hashtable.

### Hashtable

**STEP 1.**
Basically, how the index for key is decided in hashtable is

```
index = hashfunc(key_you_want_to_distribute) % array_size
```

look for [choosing hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Choosing_a_good_hash_function) for details.

**STEP 2.**
Then to retrieve the data you want, you just give it the the value you want to look for. It will create the hash for that value and lookup for that index.

### Cassandra

It works the same way in Distribute Hashtables/ Cassandra.

**STEP1.** In cassandra, you have to specify which fields in the records you want to include to create hash.
Say, if you have a table `User`. You may want to distribute the users by their `username`, so you decide it to be the primary key.

The fields you select to create hash is called Partition key in Cassandra world, because its deciding factor to partition the record.

Then, Cassandra creates hash for the record you are about to insert, then based on the range of your nodes/ machines, the record is distributed.

Say you have 3 nodes, with hash range as below,

```
node1 | 1    - 2000
node2 | 2000 - 4000
node3 | 4000 - 6000
```

For example, see following table, I'm giving random hash to make it simple. Cassandra uses Murmur3 hash in real.

```
username  | hash(example) | which node it goes to  |
----------|---------------|------------------------|
prayagupd | 1             | node1                  |
mike      | 3000          | node2                  |
zach      | 5000          | node3                  |
```

**STEP2.** Then if you want to retrieve user with username `'prayagupd'`, cassandra will create the hash for it, say its `1` and it knows that 1 belongs to node1 (1-2000).

Bingo!!!

Comment: well explained! may be a suggestion of improvement. Instead of "You may want to distribute the users by their username, so you decide it to be the primary key." better: "You may want to distribute the users by their username, so you decide it to be the PARTITION KEY PART OF primary key.". Since a (compound) primary key may contain a clustering key part, which is not considered during the partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

It is also important to understand that a partition in cassandra all resides on one node while  other things like the open source playorm for cassandra project have a partition residing on all nodes so you get more disk parallelism when accessing lots of records in a single partition.  If you need to get 500k records from a partition you may not want to use cassandra partitioning but do your own virtual partitioning like PlayOrm does.

http://buffalosw.com/products/playorm/