# Size of cassandra partitions

Tags: cassandra

What is the best tool to find the number of rows in each Cassandra partition? I have a big partition and I want to know how much records are there in that partition

Comment: By partition you mean what is the  data distribution on each node? Like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566539/data-distribution-in-cassandra

Comment: Cassandra partition: 

https://www.datastax.com/resources/tutorials/partitioning-and-replication

Comment: Partition key is a token that identifies on which node we should look for data. The clustering key on the other hand is used to find data in single node faster. So you want to check how many clustering keys are for each partition key? You could check distribution with : nodetool ring

Comment: I want a tool like 'nodetool toppartitions' but not for a period of time

Answer (score 10):

`nodetool tablehistograms <keyspace> <table>` will give you the distribution of the cells and sizes of thee partition for the table. But that does not give you for sure that partition. To get the specific one you must use count(*) on a `select` query that specifies the partition key in where clause. A very large partition and that can fail though.

`sstablemetadata` after [4.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11483) is based off the describe command in [sstable-tools](https://github.com/tolbertam/sstable-tools). It will give you the partitions largest in size, and largest in number of rows, and the partitions with most tombstones if you provide the `-s` to scan the sstable. These can be used against 3.0 and 3.11 sstables. I think 2.1 sstables are not able to be processed though.

```
...
Partitions: 22515                                                               
Rows: 13579337
Tombstones: 0
Cells: 13579337
Widest Partitions: 
  [12345] 999999
  [99049] 62664
  [99007] 60437
  [99017] 59728
  [99010] 59555
Largest Partitions: 
  [12345] 189888705
  [99049] 2965017
  [99007] 2860391
  [99017] 2826094
  [99010] 2818038
...
```

above example has parititon key an int, it will print out key like:

```
Widest Partitions: 
  [frodo] 1
Largest Partitions: 
  [frodo] 104
```

Comment: count it's not a good solution in big partitions. I want a tool that analyse the sstables and find the size of partitions

Comment: Your best bet is to do a `select` and process it client side. Spark connector does it well if have that infrastructure setup. for an offline tool `sstablemetadata` and maybe https://github.com/tolbertam/sstable-tools will be worth looking at

Comment: There are no any offline tools that count partition records

Comment: you can do `select count(*)` on the data directory with sstable-tools and it will count the rows offline, no timeout or anything to worry about.

Comment: Please explain more about 'count' with sstable-tools

Comment: it counts the number of rows in the partition with a given where clause. It builds a reader from a sstable (or directory of sstables) and applies the count aggregation function. It kinda extends cassandra-all and builds a new selectstatement that works offline without the schema loaded or anything providing all the sstables use the same metadata. Theres a "fake" cqlsh that runs against a set of sstables instead of a C* instance.

Comment: Please give an example

Comment: `select count(*) from sstables where pk = ... (depending on schema)` Look at the github page linked above

Comment: It's interesting but unfortunately, it has some bugs

Answer (score 0):

You can find the total number of partitions available for a table with nodetool command. `./nodetool cfstats <keyspace>.<table>.`

If you know the partition key, you can fire a select count(*) for the partition to get no. of the records in that partition. It's possible that query can timeout for count queries on big partitions `set  cqlsh request-timeout` before executing the query.

To understand how to calculate the physical partition size, go through the [Datastax DS220: Data Modeling partition size](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/ds220-data-modeling?unit=physical-partition-size)

Answer (score 0):

Instaclustr has a tool to find the partition size.  However, this does not show the number of records in each partition:

https://github.com/instaclustr/cassandra-sstable-tools

Answer (score 0):

- As mentioned above either use inbuilt node tool, which could be find within Cassandra Folder extracted from jar , and run nodetool inside terminal .
  [image: path of nood tool]

  nodetool toppartitions

- Additionally you can also use online tool such as : https://www.cqlguru.io/ , but this need some prior information as vaerage number of rows per partition, average number of text in varchar and all . But this tool is good for rough estimation.